# Form_validation - How to show specific error in error_list

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm currently trying to find a way to only display specific errors of an error list.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'lang:user.password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|matches[password_confirm]');
```

I want to be able to show a message if the field is empty like "Some fields are missing". But I want to show a specific message if the user only write a password shorther than 6 characters or higher than 12 like "The password length must be between 6 and 12 characters"

Thx.

Comment: you wan to do this whit forms ? could not get what your trying to say

Answer (score 4):

I encourage you to read the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors).  You can :

- Edit this file "language/english/form_validation_lang.php" to change the default error messages.
- Dynamically set error messages with :

  ```
  $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s must not be empty.');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s must be between 6 and 12 characters.');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', '%s must be between 6 and 12 characters.');
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set your rules, you simply make sure that you include

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

somewhere in your form.

You can also show an individual error using something like this:-

```
<?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
```

More info here:- [Form Validation : CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)